# How to resolve 502 Mysql query error on Netlify (Express server)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, amazon-rds, netlify

I have a React app + Express server deployed on netlify [here](https://5d4c99c51fb738e69d3085d4--frosty-visvesvaraya-268d4b.netlify.com/). I have a simple api endpoint that queries my MySql DB on AWS.

When I make the api request I am given a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502".

If I just return a simple 
`res.send("simple response")`
 then everything works fine and I get the response on the client. Could someone point me in the right direction on what I should be looking for?

I've tried to disable the skip_name_resolve parameter on my db to see if the hostname mattered, opening up access to all ports / ip's on the aws security group, look up common examples of express + mysql server implementations, lookup the netlify function docs, and using async await in the server.

```
// client.jsx
useEffect( () => {
    fetch("/.netlify/functions/server/api/getSalesData")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res));

// server.js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const serverless = require('serverless-http');
const mysql = require("mysql");
const db = mysql.createConnection({ ... });

db.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('You are now connected...')
});

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.get("/api/getSalesData", (req, res) => {
    // res.send({ express: "Hello from express" });
    db.query("SELECT * FROM Sales LIMIT 5", (err, rows) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(rows);
    });
});

app.use('/.netlify/functions/server', router);
module.exports = app;
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

Comment: is the RDS instance publicly accessable?

Comment: @SándorBakos yes I just checked and it said it is. I wish that was the problem haha